# How to make user inactive by default while registering?

Tags: user-access

When user registers to my site I want to make them inactive by default so I can manually update their status and send them their login info. I am using wordpress 3.1.2. Is it possible? Are there any plugins for this?

BTW, I am using Cimy User Extra Field plugin to add more fields to the registration page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/*
Plugin Name: Role-less New Users
Description: Removes all roles from new registrations.
Author: 5ubliminal
*/
// Hook into the registration process
add_action('user_register', function($user_id){
    $user = new WP_User($user_id);
    // Remove all user roles after registration
    foreach($user->roles as $role){
        $user->remove_role($role);
    }
}, 11);
```

Create a new *.php* file. Paste the code above in it. Put it in your */wp-content/plugins* folder and activate it. **Do test it!**

**PS**: *Be advised, PHP 5.3 syntax, closures used. Incompatible with PHP 5.2 or older.*